# Dynamic (auto increment) input length (count) on a linear regression channel drawing, starting from given bar_index/datetime in Pine Script language

Tags: plot, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

My question is [about the Linear Regression drawing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#linear-regression).

The example in the documentation uses a fixed length (100), and is therefore :

- shifting to the right on each new bar
- of constant width (here 100 bars)

I'm trying to make it start from a custom point in time (x bars from now or bar_index or datetime...), so that :

- it keeps extending on each new bar
- but the starting point remains on the same location (until we change it in the settings).

That means that the **length** (input) would be **dynamic and increase on each new bar**.

I am getting the following error : `Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back in the study or strategy function.`

Is it possible to do ?

Here is the code

```
//@version=4
study("Linear Regression", shorttitle="LinReg", overlay=true)

upperMult = input(title="Upper Deviation", defval=2)
lowerMult = input(title="Lower Deviation", defval=-2)

useUpperDev = input(title="Use Upper Deviation", defval=true)
useLowerDev = input(title="Use Lower Deviation", defval=true)
showPearson = input(title="Show Pearson's R", defval=true)
extendLines = input(title="Extend Lines", defval=false)

// ====================================================================
// ====================================================================

// Original parameter (the one that should increments)
// len = input(title="Count", defval=100)

// Unsuccessful attempt : "Starting from given bar_index"
barIndexOfStartingBar = 6392 - 80 // 6392 : Current bar_index, 80 : Offset to the starting bar
len = bar_index - barIndexOfStartingBar
len := nz(len[1]) + 1

// Unsuccessful attempt : "x bars from current bar"
startingPointFromCurrentBar = input(title="Count", defval=80)
len = (bar_index + startingPointFromCurrentBar) - bar_index
len := nz(len[1]) + 1

// ====================================================================
// ====================================================================

src = input(title="Source", defval=close)

extend = extendLines ? extend.right : extend.none

calcSlope(src, len) =>
    if not barstate.islast or len <= 1
        [float(na), float(na), float(na)]
    else
        sumX = 0.0
        sumY = 0.0
        sumXSqr = 0.0
        sumXY = 0.0
        for i = 0 to len - 1
            val = src[i]
            per = i + 1.0
            sumX := sumX + per
            sumY := sumY + val
            sumXSqr := sumXSqr + per * per
            sumXY := sumXY + val * per
        slope = (len * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (len * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)
        average = sumY / len
        intercept = average - slope * sumX / len + slope
        [slope, average, intercept]

[s, a, i] = calcSlope(src, len)

startPrice = i + s * (len - 1)
endPrice = i
var line baseLine = na

if na(baseLine) and not na(startPrice)
    baseLine := line.new(bar_index - len + 1, startPrice, bar_index, endPrice, width=1, extend=extend, color=color.red)
else
    line.set_xy1(baseLine, bar_index - len + 1, startPrice)
    line.set_xy2(baseLine, bar_index, endPrice)
    na

calcDev(src, len, slope, average, intercept) =>
    upDev = 0.0
    dnDev = 0.0
    stdDevAcc = 0.0
    dsxx = 0.0
    dsyy = 0.0
    dsxy = 0.0

    periods = len - 1

    daY = intercept + (slope * periods) / 2
    val = intercept

    for i = 0 to periods
        price = high[i] - val
        if (price > upDev)
            upDev := price

        price := val - low[i]
        if (price > dnDev)
            dnDev := price

        price := src[i]
        dxt = price - average
        dyt = val - daY

        price := price - val
        stdDevAcc := stdDevAcc + price * price
        dsxx := dsxx + dxt * dxt
        dsyy := dsyy + dyt * dyt
        dsxy := dsxy + dxt * dyt
        val := val + slope

    stdDev = sqrt(stdDevAcc / (periods == 0 ? 1 : periods))
    pearsonR = dsxx == 0 or dsyy == 0 ? 0 : dsxy / sqrt(dsxx * dsyy)
    [stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev]

[stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev] = calcDev(src, len, s, a, i)

upperStartPrice = startPrice + (useUpperDev ? upperMult * stdDev : upDev)
upperEndPrice = endPrice + (useUpperDev ? upperMult * stdDev : upDev)
var line upper = na

lowerStartPrice = startPrice + (useLowerDev ? lowerMult * stdDev : -dnDev)
lowerEndPrice = endPrice + (useLowerDev ? lowerMult * stdDev : -dnDev)
var line lower = na

if na(upper) and not na(upperStartPrice)
    upper := line.new(bar_index - len + 1, upperStartPrice, bar_index, upperEndPrice, width=1, extend=extend, color=#0000ff)
else
    line.set_xy1(upper, bar_index - len + 1, upperStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(upper, bar_index, upperEndPrice)
    na

if na(lower) and not na(lowerStartPrice)
    lower := line.new(bar_index - len + 1, lowerStartPrice, bar_index, lowerEndPrice, width=1, extend=extend, color=#0000ff)
else
    line.set_xy1(lower, bar_index - len + 1, lowerStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(lower, bar_index, lowerEndPrice)
    na

// Pearson's R
var label r = na
transparent = color.new(color.white, 100)
label.delete(r[1])
if showPearson and not na(pearsonR)
    r := label.new(bar_index - len + 1, lowerStartPrice, tostring(pearsonR, "#.################"), color=transparent, textcolor=#0000ff, size=size.normal, style=label.style_labelup)
```

[image: Screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

With these changes you should be able to go back a few thousand bars:

```
study("Linear Regression", shorttitle="LinReg", overlay=true, max_bars_back = 4999)
```

and either one of these:

```
// #1
offsetToStart = input(100, minval = 1, step = 100)
len = max(1, offsetToStart)

// #2
startingBar = input(10000, minval = 1, step = 100)
len = max(1, bar_index - startingBar)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  
  
• Solution 1 : seems to do the same as the script provided in the documentation (the one posted in the question).  
• Solution 2 : initializes OK but crashes when the next bar appears (eg : bar-replay) : "Internal server study error".  
  
What I'm trying to achieve is to have the channel starting at a given bar_index (configurable in the settings) and that the channel increases on each new bar.
That mean if the channel starts at bar_index 2000, the length for it's calculations would calculated by the program.

Comment: As an example, when launching the indicator. If the starting bar of the channel was 10 bars away from the current bar, the situation would be : `a channel starting at bar_index 2000, of width 10 (until current bar)`.
10 bars later, we would have : `a channel starting at bar_index 2000, of width 20 (until current bar).`

Is that possible in Pine Script?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called anchoring. You can do this with a trick. What I usually do is the following:

```
p = input("D", title="Period", type=input.resolution)
offsetToStart = input(0, title="Begin Offset") // remove the minval

newbar(p) => change(time(p)) == 0?0:1
nb = newbar(p)
bars = barssince(nb) + offsetToStart
var line l1 = na
l1 := line.new(bar_index[bars], open, bar_index[bars], open + syminfo.mintick, extend=extend.both)
line.delete(l1[1])
```

Remember to remove the minval. Chose the period and you can now anchor beginning of your indicator. Playaround with `p`